# How to deploy war file on JETTY server

Tags: java, mysql, jetty, war

after completing my first java web application (it's small application) the local server used jetty server and database is MySQL.

How to deploy war file on web server.

any suggestions for tutorials  or links please share...

i googled it but lot of unwanted items are there so please help if you know about his please share answers

Comment: don't use jetty myself, but for my experience: if you have it registered in your IDE, and start/stop it from there, you can also 'add' the war there.
otherwise, try by putting the war into the 'webapps' folder of your server and start it up

Comment: Is [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Deploy_Web_Applications) what you need?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Download an Apache tomcat. Copy your war file to webapps folder. Start the tomcat from bin folder. 
Thats it!!

Comment: How is this a accepted answer tot he question of how to deploy war file in Jetty. Lolz

Comment: Please add some further explanation. How does "deploy war file on web server" relate to installing a new software?